# Import MQIC.DLL in C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

In my system, I need to load MQIC.DLL (IBM WebSphere MQ) to send and get messages to a MQ server.

Currently, this service is running in VB5, and I need to upgrade to .Net. When I try to load this library, I get the error:

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

The code:

```
[DllImport("MQIC.DLL", EntryPoint = "MQCONNstd@16", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void MQCONN(string QMgrName, long Hconn, long CompCode, long Reason);
```

Does anybody have idea why it's happening?

The VB5 code:

```
Declare Sub MQCONN Lib "MQIC.DLL" Alias "MQCONNstd@16" (ByVal QMgrName As String, Hconn As Long, CompCode As Long, Reason As Long)
```

This is MQOD struct:

```
public struct MQOD
{
    public String StrucId; //Structure identifier'
    public long Version; //Structure version number'
    public long ObjectType; //Object type'
    public string ObjectName; //Object name'
    public string ObjectQMgrName; //Object queue manager name'
    public string DynamicQName; //Dynamic queue name'
    public string AlternateUserId; //Alternate user identifier'
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show the working VB5 Declare statement or the native export prototype.

Comment: I added a comment with the code in VB5. Tks.

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves - (*continued here*) So the `vb5` app is the client in a client server (`c++` app) setup where the client also communicates with MQIC.DLL. If you need to change the server app would depend on how the communication occurs between these 2 and what is communicated. If none of the `MQIC.DLL` structures are sent back/forth then you do not have to worry about it. If you do send those structures back and forth then you need to check if they are preserved in the same manner in the .net port, again maybe nothing to worry about.

Comment: As far as the error you should try to find if there is a header file provided for MQIC.DLL, that could help you specify the `DllImport` statements correctly.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I'm looking for this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration of `MQCONN` to use `out long` for all `long` parameters.

Check [MQ application programming reference](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q089590_.htm) for each API call, and make sure you use `out` or `ref` for every parameter described as output or input/output.

You can also look for `cmqc.h` in your MQ installation directory, provided you have installed development environment. It has declarations of all MQI calls. You can transcribe the C header to C# - wherever you see a pointer (`*`) use `out` or `ref`.

But generally speaking, you are going to be much better off using managed .Net classes for MQ, as others suggested.

Comment: It worked! It's necessary to do it for all methods? Thanks

Comment: Yuri, Thanks a lot for your post. But i have a doubt yet...The MQOPEN method have a parameter in out. In C# I declare this with ref, but not work. Do you know how i need declare it? I added the code in this post.

Comment: Don't see a problem with how you declared `MQOPEN`. What error are you getting? And how did you declare `MQOD`? Don't use my response to post it please, either amend your question or ask a new one

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new in this forum yet. I edited my original post with the MQOD struct. Thanks.

Comment: I saw in API that the field "StrucId" is MQCHAR4. Can I declare it as string?

Comment: Not exactly. `String` consists of Unicode characters, `MQCHAR4` consists of `char`s. You need to carefully map each MQ structure to the C# counterpart, using `cmqc.h` or documentation. That's definitely possible, but you are on your own with this unfortunately, and will have to debug it quite a bit. I suggest you either use C/C++ or switch to .Net classes. Learning them will not take longer than forcing C bindings to work in C#, and you will have all the support in the world, as opposed to the situation you are in right now.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ provides a .NET interface. I recommend you to use that instead of MQIC DLL. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029250_.htm. There are many samples shipped with the product.

Comment: Shashi, in our server is running a c++ program with this DLL version with some specific things from our business. This application in server have been running since 2002 together the VB5 program. In this upgrade, my idea isn't change this implementation, but only upgrade to .net.

Comment: It's impossible to use MQIC.DLL in C#?

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves - I believe this answer is a good one. If there is a managed library available that does exactly what the native library does but is geared towards .net then why not use it? This does not change the implementation unless the managed library offers a completely different set of functionality which I doubt as otherwise it would not have been suggested as an answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "only upgrade to .NET"? It's possible to call APIs in a C DLL from C#.

Comment: Because the dll that we used today was developed in VB5. How this software will be removed from the company, it's necessary to convert all applications that currently are using this plataform. But we haven't time to developing a new solution with this dll, our target is simply convert the application from VB5 to C#.

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves - there is no such thing as "simply convert" between VB5 and c#. You have to do a re-write although the logic stays the same. It makes sense to use the managed dll provided by the manufacturer instead of trying to force the native dll to work with your new platform. You will only be saving time during the rewrite by doing so, by ignoring that advice and using the native dll you will probably create more problems and spend more time than by following their advise.

Comment: @Igor, I understand you, but the server is running a c++ program that is compatible with VB5 library. If I rewrite this code, it's possible that be necessary to rewrite also c++ program, and it's isn't good for now. The VB5 program have many specific methods and a singular way to connect to MQ server, and change it now it's very dangerous for my project.

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves - I am not following you at all. You asked how to get a new .net app to connect to IBM websphere. This can be done using their managed library (from the .net app). How does/can that influence some other c++ program? If there is more you are not telling us please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Igor - This structure was developed in 2002. Were created two applications  - one installed on server (C++) and another installed on client (VB5). The two applications were based in native libraries from MQ: MQMSTD.DLL (Server) e MQIC.DLL (Client). The application in client (VB) have many specific methods to connect with server, including a way to get answers. If i use IBM MQ .NET interface, 
probably I will need also to rewrite C++ application. I do not know if I could explain in a clear way. 
I understand that the best way is continue using the library MQIC.DLL.

Comment: I made a test now. If I use the VB5 DLL in C#, It's possible to put the message in the queue and it is processed by the server. When I try to send the message using IBM.WMQ library, the server answer is: "Unexpected message command." I think that it occured because the server is waiting a message in a specific protocol, that was write in VB5 DLL. therefore I need to convert VB5 program to C# without change.